# Payment information for Stripe Billing

Tags: stripe-payments, billing, recurring-billing

I want to use Stripe Billing for recurring payments.

How do I collect payment information for this? I assume I'm supposed to use the Stripe Payments form, but this isn't spelled out anywhere I can see.

How does the flow between the two work? Is there an example implemented anywhere I can see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few steps involved here:

1. You collect a customer's credit card information with a form using Checkout, Elements or a mobile SDK, it's securely sent to Stripe. In return you get back a token.

   - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout
   - https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart
   - https://stripe.com/docs/mobile
2. You take this token, pass it off to your backend, where you tell Stripe to save the token to a Customer. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer
3. You can then start a Subscription with the card that has been saved on this Customer. https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription

If you want to see all the pieces come together, https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart

Comment: Thanks. I did read the https://stripe.com/docs/billing/quickstart page, but I missed the sentence about how to collect the payment information.